# Redux-Form. Как получить formValueSelector формы, когда имя формы передается в пропсах?

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

Здесь - http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/examples/selectingFormValues/ есть пример по работе с `formValueSelector`, он прекрасно работает. 
Как видно, имя формы в примере указывается явно

```
 const selector = formValueSelector('selectingFormValues') // <-- same as form name
```

Но как быть, если идентификатор формы у меня задается через `props`, ибо форм может быть несколько на странице + один и тот же компонент используется как для создания так и для редактирование модели.

```
let MyForm = (props) => {
    return(
        <Form form={props.form || 'default_name'}> 
        ..........
        </Form>
    )
} 
MyForm = reduxForm({
    fields:[.........],
    validate
})(MyForm)

const selector = formValueSelector(??) // Как мне достать идентификатор формы?
.................
```

Comment: Redux-form создает в redux отдельный стейт на каждую форму. Если родительский компонент подключен к redux то можно узнать id формы оттуда: this.props.form.<formName>

Comment: вы видимо не поняли вопроса. Родительской компонент, в данном случае компонента MyForm передает пропс form, т.е. функции (в моем случае именно функции) `MyForm` передается объект в котором имеется свойство form, и внутри этой функции я "всё знаю". Селектор же, используется ВНЕ функции, и доступа к `props` там нет. Вопрос я уже решил и отписал его как ответ.. Т.е. я решил не  использовать `formSelector` для доступа к значениям.. а сразу, контейнером передаю `form.<formName>.values`

Answer (score 0):

Вобщем ничего более элегантного я не придумал, как вообще убрать `formValueSelector` и из контейнера передавать значения формы пропсами.

Я буду рад узнать другие решения.